# Counting sessions from IPs within a certain time window

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I am using `Amazon Redshift`.

I have a list of IP addresses. There could be many entries from the same IP address, but with a different `session_id` within a certain time window (say 15 minutes for the sake of argument). I would like to count these sessions for any given IP address within this time window.

In other words, I would like to know how many sessions logged in from a certain IP address within any 15 minute time window.

So I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.client_ip,
             COUNT(DISTINCT t2.session_id) AS sessions
      FROM t AS t1
        JOIN t AS t2
          ON t1.client_ip = t2.client_ip
         AND t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.created_at
         AND dateadd (MINUTE,15,t1.created_at)
      GROUP BY t1.client_ip
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.session_id) >= 5
      ORDER BY t1.client_ip
```

Unfortunately the query is taking too long and also returns the incorrect results. There has to be a better way to achieve this. There are about 18 Million distinct IP addresses in the table and the table itself has about 400 Million+ records.

Here's some sample data:

```
Client_ip    Session_id    created_at
1.0.0.0       abc         <timestamp>
1.0.0.0       def         <timestamp> + 5 minutes
1.0.0.0       ghi         <timestamp> + 25 minutes
2.0.0.0       jkl         <timestamp1>
2.0.0.0       mno         <timestamp1> + 10 minutes
2.0.0.0       pqr         <timestamp1> + 20 minutes
```

Required result:

```
Client_ip    #Sessions
1.0.0.0       2          (sessions abc and def)
2.0.0.0       2          (sessions mno and pqr)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps the question wasn't as clear. I apologize for that.

I am not looking to have a set time window where I can create intervals of time 15 minutes apart. I would like to count the number of sessions in ANY 15 minute window from a certain IP address.

**For example: In the sample data I have posted, sessions `mno` and `pqr` should be counted (for their IP address) because they fall within 15 minutes of each other. Similarly, sessions `abc` and `def` should also be counted for their respective IP address because they fall within 15 minutes of each other. I didn't create an external start time for it. The query should ideally compare every record, with every other record, with the same IP address. There shouldn't be a need to create an external start time.**

Here's the output of `explain <query>`

```
    XN Subquery Scan derived_table1  (cost=6516525010733.39..6516525010733.41 rows=2 width=524)
  ->  XN Merge  (cost=6516525010733.39..6516525010733.39 rows=2 width=1032)
        Merge Key: t1.client_ip
        ->  XN Network  (cost=6516525010733.39..6516525010733.39 rows=2 width=1032)
              Send to leader
              ->  XN Sort  (cost=6516525010733.39..6516525010733.39 rows=2 width=1032)
                    Sort Key: t1.client_ip
                    ->  XN HashAggregate  (cost=5516525010733.36..5516525010733.38 rows=2 width=1032)
                          Filter: (count(DISTINCT session_id) >= 10)
                          ->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_BOTH  (cost=6284418.61..5516506756947.79 rows=2433838076 width=1032)
                                Outer Dist Key: t2.client_ip
                                Inner Dist Key: t1.client_ip
                                Hash Cond: (("outer".client_ip)::text = ("inner".client_ip)::text)
                                Join Filter: (("inner".created_at <= "outer".created_at) AND ("outer".created_at <= date_add('minute'::text, 15::bigint, "inner".created_at)))
                                ->  XN Seq Scan on fbs_page_view_staging t2  (cost=0.00..6279185.96 rows=2093062 width=1040)
                                      Filter: ((created_at <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                ->  XN Hash  (cost=6279185.96..6279185.96 rows=2093062 width=524)
                                      ->  XN Seq Scan on fbs_page_view_staging t1  (cost=0.00..6279185.96 rows=2093062 width=524)
                                            Filter: ((created_at <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at >= '2017-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
----- Tables missing statistics: fbs_page_view_staging -----
----- Update statistics by running the ANALYZE command on these tables -----
```

Comment: Can you try to use a subquery to get all the rows first? Like (SELECT * FROM t WHERE created_at BETWEEN now -15 and now) and use that for your calculations.

Comment: @clinomaniac Thanks so much for your reply. This would be good if I had a `start_date` that I could rely upon. The `start_date` is rolling in this case. I am looking for the # of sessions within ANY 15 minute time window.

Comment: is your table distributed by `client_ip` and sorted by `(client_ip, created_at)`?

Comment: Any query-optimization question should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in the query, and the output of `EXPLAIN <query>` for your query.

Comment: Added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in mind..

```
SELECT t1.client_ip, t1.session_id, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.session_id)
FROM  ( SELECT client_ip, session_id, MIN(created_at) created_at
                     FROM   fbs_page
                     GROUP BY client_ip, session_id) AS t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT client_ip, session_id, MIN(created_at) created_at
                     FROM   fbs_page
                     GROUP BY client_ip, session_id) AS t2
         ON t1.client_ip = t2.client_ip
            AND t1.session_id != t2.session_id 
            AND t1.created_at 
            BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,t2.created_at) AND t2.created_at
GROUP BY t1.client_ip, t1.session_id
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

After some discussion, I think this might be close to what you need. You can add where clause to filter results as need for shorter date span or other things to make it run faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. This would be good if I had a start_date that I could rely upon. The start_date is rolling in this case. I am looking for the # of sessions within ANY 15 minute time window.

Comment: Any as in predefined? Or current? If current then you can use SYSDATE or something. Ir specific window then you can pass the date to the CHECK_DATE variable.

Comment: There isn't a fixed `start_date`. It could be anything that's available in the `created_at` column.

Comment: So 15 mins window for each session?

Comment: Edited based on comments. Let me know if my understanding of the requirement is not correct.

Comment: I have edited my question to add more details. Sorry if it wasn't clear earlier. Your query creates an explicit `max(created_at)`. I would like this window to be rolling. Every record should be compared with every other record, bearing the same IP address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161142/discussion-between-clinomaniac-and-patthebug).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.client_ip, t1.WindowStart, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.session_id) AS sessions
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT client_ip, 
                        created_at as WindowStart, 
                        DATEADD(MINUTE,15,created_at) as WindowEnd
        FROM t
        -- Add a where clause in here if you want to reduce the number of rows that you're working with
        -- e.g. WHERE created_at BETWEEN 'some_arbitrary_date' AND 'another_arbitrary_date'
     ) t1
  INNER JOIN t as t2 ON t1.client_ip = t2.client_ip 
                    AND t2.created_at BETWEEN t1.WindowStart AND t1.WindowEnd
GROUP BY t1.client_ip, t1.WindowStart
```

Comment: I have added more details to the question. I cannot create a table of external start and end times. I would like the window to be rolling.